# Windows CMD Commands corresponding to linux commands Needed

Tags: linux, windows, unix, batch-file, cmd

I have few Linux commands and I need to change them to Windows Commands. Also, is there any good tutorial which can help me in learning such corresponding commands?

```
export ML_SERIALIZE_DIR=/Users/Mxyz/ML

export ML_SERIALIZE_GRAPH=true

echo ML_SERIALIZE_DIR = $ML_SERIALIZE_DIR

echo ML_SERIALIZE_GRAPH = $ML_SERIALIZE_GRAPH 

java -DCL_LOG_DIR="/Users/Mxyz/ML" -classpath .:lib/:Ml-mobxyz-import.jar org.xy.mobxyz.mobxyz.ML

echo "Batch program is complete"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is direct translation of the shell commands.

```
set ML_SERIALIZE_DIR=/Users/Mxyz/ML
set ML_SERIALIZE_GRAPH=true
echo ML_SERIALIZE_DIR = %ML_SERIALIZE_DIR%
echo ML_SERIALIZE_GRAPH = %ML_SERIALIZE_GRAPH%
java -DCL_LOG_DIR="/Users/Mxyz/ML" -classpath .;lib;Ml-mobxyz-import.jar org.xy.mobxyz.mobxyz.ML
```

- Replaced `export`s with `set`s.
- Variable `$var` is replaced with `%var%`
- Class path separator in windows is `;` instead of `:`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I have one question. The commands that I have written in my question are in .sh file. Will your suggested windows command work in .bat file? also what will be the corresponding windows command fir echo "Batch Program is complete"?

Comment: @Anilkumar, The commands given in the answer is workin batch file (`.bat`). I don't know about the second question. Please post a separated question for that.

Comment: ok...I think the typo mistake "fir" must have confused you... I am looking for corresponding windows command for linux command- echo "Batch program is complete"

Comment: @Anilkumar, `echo Batch program is complete` (without quotes)

Comment: @Falsetru... if I want to replace the dir path to "D:\ML", will the set and java command look like this- set ML_SERIALIZE_DIR=D:\ML and java -DCL_LOG_DIR="D:\ML" ?

Comment: @Anilkumar, Yes it is. `"` is optional unless there's space(s).

Comment: ok...and there is no need to replace : with ; in the path?right?

Comment: Posting multiple follow-up questions in comments are not a very good use of Stack Overflow. One, you are unduly burdening the person who already helped you; two, not many others will even see your comments here. Accept this answer and post a new question with full details, if you can't figure it out.

Comment: @Anilkumar, I don't know `:` work in Windows. You'd better explicitly change it to `;` to be safe. BTW, as tripleee comment, please post a separated question if you have another question.